# Exterior glass on oven doors, are there alternatives

Tags: doors, oven, replacement, glass, range

The external glass on our oven door was recently shattered. And I was wondering what my options were for replacing it. Could I make a stained glass window, does tempered glass come in anything other then plain glass?? What are my options? Does it have to be tempered glass?

Comment: yes it has to be tempered

Comment: i believe it is double glass

Comment: Might be able to put two sheets in to make it triple

Comment: "Stained Glass" implies lead caning to hold the pieces in place. Lead melts at 327.5°C. While 621°F is higher than most ovens heat in normal cooking, I do believe that they can get to 600°F or higher in "self-cleaning" mode, which would lead to your lead melting and the window disintegrating. Have you considered simply buying a replacement door? If the oven is moderately recent (40 years old or less), you'll probably be able to find one available at an on-line parts store.

Comment: or a replacement window from the mfgr.